# Are questions about Flash animations/ads on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Flash has a wide range of possible uses.  It can be used as a video playback engine for FLV video, which is clearly on topic, but it can also be used as a (possibly interactive) vector animation system that outputs to fla files or similar.

Do we want to consider all flash questions on topic or are some questions, such as how to make a flash based ad that isn't using video elements, off topic?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would say that unless the Flash project is either a player for a video project or being used to form an output of an animation to a more traditional video format, then it should be considered off topic for video production.

The workflow and capabilities of Flash animations are very different from the way in which Video Production operates and while some of the basic tweening concepts are similar to keyframe animation in After Effects, the basic format and the way that clips are managed are quite fundamentally different.

Similarly, anything worried about interactive flash development is really off topic as this is moving in to programming territory and I don't think we should be supporting ActionScript usage beyond the basics of wiring up FLV playback.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say any animation done in Flash that is exported as an .swf (or any other supported format that is running a program instead of playing a rasterized image sequence) for web or other direct embedded use (meaning you are not importing it into another program to use it in a video/further editing) I'd say it's off-topic when its about a technical question regarding the delivery of the product.

If its about animating and video use within Flash (regardless of final delivery method) it's on-topic.